# double recursion segmentation fault c++

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I've recently written this quicksort sorting algorithm. After compiling I get a "segmentation fault (core dumped)". I debugged it and it turned out that line 25 causes the problem:
v2 = quicksort(v2);
However, I do not know why I get a the "core dumped", as I have no idea what's the problem with this line.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

vector <float> quicksort(vector <float> Vec)
{
    if(Vec.size() > 1)
    {
        float pivot = Vec[(Vec.size())/2-1];

        vector <float> v1, v2;
        vector <float> V;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Vec.size(); i++)
        {
            if(Vec[i] >= pivot)
                v2.push_back(Vec[i]);
            else
                v1.push_back(Vec[i]);
        }

        v1 = quicksort(v1);
        v2 = quicksort(v2);
        //after debuggung, I found out that the line above causes the "segmentation fault (core dumped)" (line 25)

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
            V.push_back(v1[i]);
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < v2.size(); i++)
            V.push_back(v2[i]);

        return V;
    }
    else
    {
        return Vec;
    }

}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    vector <float> v;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        v.push_back(rand() % 100);
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }

    v = quicksort(v);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: how does this even compile? your quicksort takes in a vector and an int, but you only ever give it a vector...

Comment: I dont't think that the actual issue is in this code. Do you have something else in the vector in your real case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to get a totally random number using rand() you need to seed the number generator. To do this you include the "time.h" library and then write: `srand (time(NULL));`

Secondly, your quicksort takes two parameters, a vector named Vec and an int f, that isn't used for anything. Take int f of the function's parameters.

Thirdly, the problem is that an infinite loop is happening in this part of the code (lines 17 to 23):

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Vec.size(); i++){
    if(Vec[i] >= pivot)
        v2.push_back(Vec[i]);
    else
        v1.push_back(Vec[i]);
}
```

Imagine that our Vec vector is {2, 3} (this were the actual values, because we didn't seed the random number generation).

What's happening is that we have our pivot = 2, and then we are saying that if Vec[0], which is 2, is bigger or equal than the pivot, we add Vec[0] to v2, and then the same for Vec[1], which is 3.
Then this loops infinitely, because then you say `v2 = quicksort(v2);`. That will make Vec = v2. And that means that it will never get smaller, because, again, Vec is {2, 3}, and therefore our pivot = 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second argument was not in the original code (I don't know why it appeared here). Thanks for the tip on random numbers, I will note that in the future. Now I see that you are correct; this is indeed an infinite loop. I helped a lot

Comment: BTW, don't use `rand()` in C++, use the `<random>` header. It gives much better randomness, control, and code structure.

Answer (score 0):

It goes in stack overflow.

If the pivot is the maximum number of the vector Vec it has to be dragged from Vinf into Vsup.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

vector <float> quicksort(vector <float> Vec) {        //the int f was never used un the function
    if (Vec.size() > 1){
        vector <float> Vinf, Vsup, Vtmp;
        Vinf.push_back(Vec[(Vec.size()) / 2 - 1]);
        float pivot = Vinf[0];
        Vec.erase(Vec.begin() + Vec.size() / 2 - 1);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Vec.size(); i++)
            Vec[i] > pivot ? Vsup.push_back(Vec[i]) : Vinf.push_back(Vec[i]);
        if (Vinf.size() == Vec.size() + 1) {
            Vsup.push_back(pivot);
            Vinf.erase(Vinf.begin());
        }
        Vinf = quicksort(Vinf);
        Vsup = quicksort(Vsup);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Vinf.size(); Vtmp.push_back(Vinf[i++]));
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Vsup.size(); Vtmp.push_back(Vsup[i++]));
        return Vtmp;
    }
    else
        return Vec;
}

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    vector <float> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; cout << v[i++] << " ")
        v.push_back(rand() % 100);
    cout << endl;
    v = quicksort(v);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); cout << v[i++] << " ");
    return 0;
}
```